in Apache storm how to change supervisor id
I copied the VM containing Storm supervisor on it. when start both VMs with a master to setup a Storm cluster, in Storm UI shows only one supervisor.
In another word, both supervisors has same id so Storm is confused and show only one of them in Storm UI.
how to change the storm supervisor id in one of VM's supervisors?
PS. I have set supervisor.id : "my_custom_id" in supervisor's ./conf/storm.yaml but it does not affected.

I have found the solution that want to share with you!
when setting up a storm supervisor, you set in supervisor's ./conf/storm.yaml as follows:
storm.local.dir: /home/Documents/var/lib/storm

when starting supervisor for first time, it make a id.version file in this folder that is the supervisor id, so if you want new id in second copied VM's supervisor, you just need set another address for storm.local.dir
PS: if it is in /home/ directory no need to grant permission otherwise you need to do it as follows:
sudo chown pi:pi -R  /var/var/lib/storm (address you determined)
